# Hangul, but not vertical or horizontal

Tags: meaning, hangul

I know this might be a little too late, but I wanted the Hangul spelling of Dreamcatcher as a tattoo.

I know it should be written horizontally and read from left to right, but it was placed behind the ear going from top to bottom.

The issue is after looking at it the artist didn’t stack them (though that should also be the question)

Attached is a picture of how it looks. Did this turn out offensively or is it still okay even though it technically can still be read left to right if you tilt your head? Ugh. I’m sorry :([image]

Comment: Whether it is vertical or horizontal should not be any problem at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That’s really good to know—but just to be sure—the Hangul was printed horizontally and placed vertically so it is sideways. Is that still okay? I appreciate you!

Comment: Yes. It is not a problem at all.

Comment: It’s just a word lying on its right side. No problems with reading it.

Comment: It's the same as if you wrote out "Insomnia" and then just rotated that 90 degrees. Might be slightly confusing at first glance, but it's perfectly easy to read. The proportions of some characters does seem off though, but that could be due to the font used for the stencil.